# JDBC Apache derby SYSCOLUMNS Table Not Displaying Information

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

I am investigating the system tables (within the SYS Schema) in Apache Derby. I have a database that uses the Apache Derby RDBMS and I have added three tables to it called Accounts, Customers and Employees. The database runs behind a Java application that runs queries against these three tables to perform any one of the CRUD functions (these queries work fine so no issue there)

What I want to do is to get meta data about the tables I created through the system tables in the database (the table names, column names, data in the tables etc) using SQL (not Java's classes, which I do know about) rather than simply querying the actual tables themselves. I've looked at the reference to the tables on the [Derby system tables](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.3/ref/rrefsistabs38369.html)
page and I think that the tables that I should be focusing on are SYSCOLUMNS and SYSTABLES. What's odd is that SYSTABLES shows information about my tables but SYSCOLUMNS does not.

There are other tables in the SYS schema that contain data about my tables, such as SYSCONTSTRAINTS, SYSFOREIGNKEYS, SYSKEYS and  (as mentioned above) SYSTABLES. So to me it's somewhat peculiar that SYSCOLUMNS doesn't also have information about my tables inside them.

When I actually run a query against SYSCOLUMNS I get this error:

```
Error code 20000, SQL state XN020: Error marshalling or unmarshalling a user defined type: org.apache.derby.catalog.types.TypeDescriptorImpl
```

I think this refers to the COLUMNDATATYPE column (based on reading the reference of the SYSCOLUMNS table in the link above) but I have looked at other pages and don't really understand it.

If it helps here are the columns and data types for my tables:

**CUSTOMERS**

CUSTOMER_ID (Integer Primary Key Autoincrement (starts at 1, increments by 1))

FULL_NAME (Varchar (50))

**ACCOUNTS**

ACCOUNT_ID (Integer Primary Key Autoincrement (starts at 1, increments by 1))

CUSTOMER _ID (Integer foreign key (references CUSTOMER_ID in CUSTOMER)

ACCOUNT_TYPE (Varchar (50))

BALANCE (Double)

CREDIT_LIMIT (Double)

**EMPLOYEES**

EMPLOYEE_ID (Integer Primary Key Autoincrement (starts at 1, increments by 1))

FULL_NAME (Varchar (50))

USERNAME (Varchar (50))

PASSWORD (Varchar (50))

Apologies but I can't post any screenshots due to reputation rules (I'm signed in on my Google account). The gist of it is: SYSTABLES has data about my tables and SYSCOLUMNS doesn't and I think the above error is the cause, but I don't understand what the error is and how to fix it (if at all)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the embedded driver or the client-server driver?

And what version of Derby are you running?

I'm going to speculate, and guess that you're using the client-server driver, and that you've run into some combination of [DERBY-5407](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-5407), [DERBY-4688](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-4688), and [DERBY-4491](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-4491).

If you can package your reproduction into a simple test case, it would be great if you could log a new job at the Derby JIRA with all the details.

In the meantime, you could investigate some of the workarounds suggested by those jobs:

1. Use the embedded Derby driver, rather than the client-server driver
2. Put derby.jar and derbytools.jar into your CLASSPATH, in addition to derbyclient.jar

Comment: I'm using a client-server driver and Derby version 10.8.1.2

Comment: I tried adding derby.jar and derbytools.jar but the error still occurs. Am having issues switching to an embedded driver because a suitable driver can't be found.

Comment: You just have to include the derbytools.jar and derby.jar while adding jars and refresh the connection (as in my case by reconnecting to the database server)